# T-SQL Multiple Negative Where Conditions

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements, sql-server-2016

I have a table `A` which has `85337` rows `(Total)`.

Then the following query `(Q1)`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND c1 = 0
        AND c2 = 0
        AND c3 = 0
        AND c4 = 0;
```

returns `590` rows.

The next query `(Q2)`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND c1 != 0
        AND c2 != 0
        AND c3 != 0
        AND c4 != 0;
```

returns: `44245` rows. (should return 84747)

- Why `(Total)` does not equal sum of `(Q1)` + `(Q2)`?
- Why in the second query has to be "`OR`" instead of "`AND`" to get the "correct" values when the logic is the same? It must be trivial but cannot imagine the logic behind.

Comment: Why would you expect Total to be equal the amount of Q1 + Q2? Your data obviously isn't in such a manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) on Negation:

```
NOT (P AND Q) => (NOT P OR NOT Q)
```

Comment: Doesn't work if `P` OR `Q` is a three-valued logic predicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your two queries don't encapsulate every possible combination of your data as you are using `AND`:

```
declare @a table (c1 int,c2 int,c3 int,c4 int);
insert into @a values
 (1,1,1,1)
,(0,0,1,1)  -- This row is not returned as it doesn't meet either criteria below
,(0,0,0,0)
,(0,0,0,0);

SELECT  *
FROM    @a
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND c1 = 0
        AND c2 = 0
        AND c3 = 0
        AND c4 = 0;

SELECT  *
FROM    @a
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND c1 != 0
        AND c2 != 0
        AND c3 != 0
        AND c4 != 0;
```